# Database not selected while using phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am trying  to import a sql file , i selected **phpmyadmin**, thereafter i  went to one of the database listed on the left hand side, and then imported my sql file, but it is still showing **no database selected.**

Comment: Could you post the beggining of your SQL file?

Answer (score 1):

- If you are importing whole database via sql, then ***create a new
  database with the same name*** you want to import, and select it. And then import.
- If you are importing the table, then you must ***have to select the
  database*** to which you want to import.